# http server listening in old port

Tags: node.js, express, webmatrix

First i installed the node js with webmatrix and ran a sample node js app. the app was assigned a random port. `http://localhost:62369/`. After that i installed the express module. As said in their doc. i wrote,

```
var app = express();
app.get('/',function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world!!');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Then i restarted the server. The launched browser was still pointing to `http://localhost:62369/` instead of port 3000. Moreover `http://localhost:3000/` was not working.

Comment: Did you try another port? Maybe `3000` is busy...

Comment: Yes. i tried with '4589' but same. The new browser is launched with '62369' port

Comment: So when yo changed the port, `http://localhost:4589/` worked or not?

Comment: is this your whole code now?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani. it was not working even when i changed to 4589.

Comment: @rajkamal How you run your code?

Comment: i stopped the server. changed the listening port. started the server again.

Comment: maybe you just forget to press ctrl+s in your editor?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you've saved your code in your file (open it with another editor, maybe something's wrong with your editor), close the command line window and open it again. try to run server. I'm sure the problem is not because of node or express. Try to check everything again.

And also run your server with command line:
`cd path/folder`
`node myFile`
I don't know what are you using to run server, but if it's something with UI (in comments you mentioned a click) it can cache your code or something like that. So it's safer to run with commend line.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run this code so you can see if you have any problem on saving the code with your IDE:

```
var app = express(),
    port = 4555;
app.get('/',function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world!!');
})
console.log("Server is running on " + port);
app.listen(port);
```

After that, you need to change the `port` variable only. It's helpful if you comment what you see after running this code on the console.

Comment: In the logs im seeing 4555, but the browser that is launched when i click Run is opening with 'http://localhost:62369/'

Comment: Type this command on your terminal/command prompt: `telnet 127.0.0.1 4555` then enter and let me know what you see.

Comment: It seems that it is webmatrix that launches a browser. Maybe you did not tell it that the port changed?